# Cosmos DB: Difference between using MaxItemCount and Take() when retrieving N many records

Tags: azure, linq, async-await, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I need to take the top N records from a `Cosmos DB` container. I have noticed that I've been using two different patterns in various places in my solution and would like to stick to one approach. So far, I have treated both approaches to be the same, but I'm not 100% confident.

Approach 1:

```
container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, continuationToken, requestOptions).Where(...).ToList()
```

In this approach, I create a `QueryRequestOptions` object and set `MaxItemCount` to `n` to configure how many records I want to retrieve.

Approach 2:

```
container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>().Where(...).Take(n).ToList()
```

This uses the `Take()` method of LINQ.

- Is there any difference between the two approaches in terms of performance or something else I'm not aware of?
- Also, another challenge I have is converting these queries to async. I've noticed `ToListAsync()` isn't available, and I'm thinking I'd need to use the feed iterator which requires several lines of boilerplate code. Is there an easier way to use async here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aproach 1 and 2 calls the same code.

All 3 parameters are optional. So there is no need to send any of the parameters if you are just using the defaults.

If you are changing the parameters to something other than the defaults, you need to use approach 1.

It is recommended to always use ToFeedIterator(), and to do the asynchronous execution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemlinqqueryable?view=azure-dotnet